# onModuleInit with Rxjs operator Vs Cron Job, which would be the efficient way to check real time data in NestJs?

Tags: nestjs, scheduler

I have a scenario in which I call the **revenue Cat API** to check the **real time data** of a user's subscriptions. And then perform some other **logic / or query to database** on the bases of the data returned by revenue Cat. Let's say if the user's subscription is expired or not So to check the real time data.

**The logic/query on the bases of the data provided by revenue cat is important, it can break application if the `api calling method` doesn't work properly**

**So to check the real time data with a function running all the time, I am wondering which following approach will be overall efficient?**

**1-** Using `Cron Job` to hit the API every let's say 10 seconds , and perform all the above logic

**2-** Inside `onModuleInit()`, call or implement the logic inside an `interval(0,10000)` Observable and then subscribe.

**The call time can be different, 10 seconds is just an example**